# How to handle ListBoxItem Style Trigger on mouse captured in WPF

Tags: wpf, templates, styles, mouseevent, listboxitem

I have a listbox containing some items that have a template. The items are created at runtime. The template triggers an scale animation when the mouse is hovering over a ListBoxItem. I would like to change the background of the item when the user clicks the item. The code below does not work because I believe the IsMouseCaptured (click) is handled by the listbox selector. Any ideas how I can do this all in XAML code?

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="rec" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>    
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks an item in a listbox, it is selected, therefor your trigger needs to operate on the IsSelected-Property.

Create a style for your ListBoxItem, put the Trigger on the IsSelected-Property and set that Style as ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: That sounds reasonable to fix the background color if the item is selected. But what I would like to do is set the background color only for as long as the mouse left button is down, i.e., imitating a button behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: you gotta deselect in the MouseUp EventHandler. Other than that, I see no chance.

Answer (score 0):

As Falcon said, you could use events for your task. This can even be done purely in XAML, like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown" >
    <EventTrigger.Actions>                      
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ClickBackground">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                    Duration="0" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="rec"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>                           
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                                
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp" >
    <EventTrigger.Actions>                      
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ClickBackground" />
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave" >
    <EventTrigger.Actions>                      
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ClickBackground" />
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```